# Snake game in terminal, written in Python

Tags: python, game

I've recently wrote snake game. I Wanted to keep it in pure terminal, without libraries like pygame, tkinter or curses. It works just fine, but i know that the code might be improved. I'm rather junior programmer, and it's my first attempt at 'gamedev', because currently i'm learning Django. I would be grateful if you guys could tell me what should i change :) Here is my code:

````
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random
import time
import keyboard
import collections


class Board:
    def __init__(self, width: int, height: int, speed: float):
        self.WIDTH = width
        self.HEIGHT = height
        self.SPEED = speed
        self.board = self.__create_board()

    def __create_board(self) -> list:
        return [["□" for _ in range(self.WIDTH)] for _ in range(self.HEIGHT)]

    def print_board(self) -> None:
        print('\n')
        for row in self.board:
            print(row)


class Snake:
    def __init__(self, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.x_pos = x_pos
        self.y_pos = y_pos
        self.head_pos = [self.x_pos, self.y_pos]

        self.body_segments = collections.deque()  # doubly end operations, faster than lists
        self.length = 0
        self.apple_pos = [0, 0]
        self.coords = [0, 0]
        self.ate = False
        self.direction = 'up'
        self.spawn_apple()

    def set_empty_square(self) -> None:
        board_obj.board[self.y_pos][self.x_pos] = "□"

    def set_head(self) -> None:
        board_obj.board[self.y_pos][self.x_pos] = "■"

    def draw_body(self) -> None:
        self.body_segments.appendleft(self.coords)
        board_obj.board[self.body_segments[0][1]][self.body_segments[0][0]] = "&"
        if not self.ate:
            board_obj.board[self.body_segments[self.length][1]][self.body_segments[self.length][0]] = "□"
            self.set_head()
            self.body_segments.pop()

    def move(self) -> None:
        self.coords = [self.x_pos, self.y_pos]
        self.set_empty_square()

        if self.direction == "right":
            self.x_pos += 1
        if self.direction == "left":
            self.x_pos -= 1
        if self.direction == "up":
            self.y_pos -= 1
        if self.direction == "down":
            self.y_pos += 1

        self.set_head()
        if self.length >= 1:
            self.draw_body()

        self.head_pos = [self.x_pos, self.y_pos]

    def spawn_apple(self) -> None:
        x = random.randint(0, board_obj.WIDTH-2)
        y = random.randint(0, board_obj.HEIGHT-2)
        apple_pos = [x, y]
        if apple_pos in self.body_segments or apple_pos == self.head_pos:
            self.spawn_apple()  # if apple spawned in snake, then run func again with recursion and quit current func
            return
        self.apple_pos = [x, y]
        board_obj.board[y][x] = "●"

    def eat_apple(self) -> None:
        self.length += 1
        self.ate = True

    def collision(self) -> bool:
        return self.head_pos in self.body_segments or self.y_pos in [board_obj.HEIGHT-1, -1] \
                or self.x_pos in [board_obj.WIDTH-1, -1]


def on_press(_: None):
    for code in keyboard._pressed_events:
        if code == 105:
            snake.direction = 'left'
        elif code == 106:
            snake.direction = 'right'
        elif code == 103:
            snake.direction = 'up'
        elif code == 108:
            snake.direction = 'down'


def start_game(snake: Snake, board_obj: Board):
    snake.set_head()
    board_obj.print_board()
    keyboard.hook(on_press)
    while not snake.collision():
        print("SNAKE: ", snake.head_pos)
        print("BODY: ", snake.body_segments)
        print("APPLE: ", snake.apple_pos)

        snake.move()
        board_obj.print_board()
        snake.ate = False
        if snake.head_pos == snake.apple_pos:
            snake.eat_apple()
            snake.spawn_apple()
        time.sleep(board_obj.SPEED)
    print(f"Game over! Points: {snake.length}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    board_obj = Board(8, 8, 0.3)  # Set: width, height, speed
    snake = Snake(int(board_obj.WIDTH / 2), int(board_obj.HEIGHT / 2))  # Set: snake x and y position

    start_game(snake, board_obj)

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is good code for a first post. I'm glad to waste time discussing PEP 8 violations, and seeing a sensible use of the collections module. Having chosen good data structures is a good place to start.

For 2d arrays in Python (unless I am doing numeric heavy lifting, when using numpy is the obvious way to go) I prefer using a dictionary to a list of lists. Something like a named tuple can be used as the key. This makes the board initialization look like:

```
Pos = collections.namedtuple('position', ['x', 'y'])
...
def __create_board(self) -> None:
    self.board = {(Pos(x, y)) for x in range(self.WIDTH) for y in range(self.HEIGHT)}
```

This is a fairly big change that will ripple through the code but then you won't have to worry about [y][x] indexing or making temporary (x,y) variables.

Onto some more specific things. First, I think I would define a str method here, rather than having a print method. It adds a hidden dependency to sys.stdout in your code, and makes it harder to unit test.

```
def print_board(self) -> None:
    print('\n')
    for row in self.board:
        print(row)
```

Here I would lose the recursion and use a while True/break construction.

```
if apple_pos in self.body_segments or apple_pos == self.head_pos:
    self.spawn_apple()  # if apple spawned in snake, then run func again with recursion 
        return
```

becomes:

```
while True:
    ...
    if apple_pos not in self.body_segments and apple_pos != self.head_pos:
        break
```

I must admit to never having used the keyboard module but _pressed_events doesn't look like it is meant to be part of the API. And I don't know where the magic code numbers come from, or what key (if any) they bind to on my platform.

```
for code in keyboard._pressed_events:
    if code == 105:
        snake.direction = 'left'
```

As you never actually use the string directions I might change it to:

```
for code in keyboard.some_get_event_api_call():
    if code == LEFT_ARROW:
        snake.direction = Pos(-1, 0)
```

Then you can do the elif thing only once.

Finally:

```
int(board_obj.WIDTH / 2)
```

can be just

```
board_obj.WIDTH // 2
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I've applied all of you advices, except namedtuple, because there would be a lot of work with this code then.. But i will apply it when i'll have some more time :) Also i've splitted whole game in 3 different files and wrote some tests. Thank you again!